# My Android Library Exists on Bintray but not on jCenter

Tags: android, maven, bintray, jcenter

This is [my library on bintray](https://bintray.com/meness/maven/easyintro/1.2.9/view) but it cannot be found [on jcenter](http://jcenter.bintray.com/io/github/). People who want to use my library cannot compile their projects because my lib cannot be found. please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to click Add to JCenter button as shown in the pic

[image]

Wait a day or two then for it to be approved automatically.